# How do i check if the $# parameter with URL starts with http/https and ends with jpg/jpeg?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How can I check if a given string starts with `http`/`https` and ends with `jpg`/`jpeg`?

In other words, I want to verify the following:

1. string starts with:  `http` or `https`
2. string ends with: `jpg` `jpeg` `JPG` `JPEG

My attempt:

```
if [[ $1 = http?(s)://*.jpg ]]; then
    echo "invalid URL"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this BASH regex:

```
[[ ${1,,} =~ ^https?://.+\.jpe?g$ ]]
```

- `${1,,}` is to convert `$1` to all lowercase
- regex checks if `$1` has `http://` or `https://` at start and it ends with `jpg` or `jpeg`

Comment: Thank you so much, worked fine. how can i make it check for JPG and JPEG also as a key sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. You can set the `nocasematch` option to make it case insenstive, and you just need to add an optional `e` to the extension in the same way you checked for an optional `s` in the protocol.

```
shopt -s nocasematch
shopt -s extglob   # may not be necessary
if [[ $1 = http?(s)://*.jp?(e)g ]];
then
     echo "invalid URL"
fi
```

Older versions of `bash` may require you to turn extended pattern matching on with `shopt -s extglob` to use the `?(...)` patterns inside `[[`; newer versions treat patterns inside `[[ ... ]]` as extended patterns automatically.